# Is there a name for a learning algorithm that does no extrapolation?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

Given a set of training data, you could produce a model that simply learns the training examples themselves, i.e., the model is just a map from training examples to labels.  The model makes no prediction if it is given an example that was not in the training data.  If there are ambiguous examples in the training data, the model randomly chooses a label from the matching examples.

Is there a name for this sort of simple matching algorithm?  It's like kNN but without the need to assume a metric space (and without the ability to extrapolate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a simplistic algorithm that it really just constitutes a data structure called a *[hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)*, as applied to your training data, but with random tie breaking when two entries give the same hash code. This type of data structure is used in basic boolean queries and information retrieval.

Comment: There might be more to it than just a hash table.  For instance, you mention tie-breaking, but that implies that if one label fits the majority of instances of an ambiguous example, you throw away the other labels.  
Instead, you might want to save all of the labels associated with an example.  This could be used to choose a label randomly or, more importantly, to draw new examples from the training distribution.  It seems like there should be some name for this, but perhaps there isn't.

Comment: @Sarkom all labels are stored in a hash table. It's just a way of making a mapping between instances and labels. The random part was on he results are returned, not on how they are stored.